# Try and Except simplification for a beginner

Tags: python

Is there a way how to simplify the code flow so that `busy = 0` and `print busy` don't have to be present twice?

```
busy = 1
try:
    print 1/0
    busy = 0
    print busy
except:    
    busy = 0
    print busy
    raise
```

Comment: `busy` suggests you might want to use `finally:`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put it in the `finally` clause:

```
try:
    print 1/0
except:
    raise
finally:
    busy = 0
    print busy
```

But as @Ryan mentions in the comments now you've got a useless bit of code in the `except:` clause. So you can just do:

```
try:
    print 1/0
finally:
    busy = 0
    print busy
```

Comment: I think the point was to just have `finally` (hence the reraise), so `except:` is fine.

Comment: Ok interesting. I have not encountered a situation where `except:` was considered ok. Will update post. Thank you.

Comment: (But now you can just remove it entirely because there’s a `finally`.)

Comment: @Ryan: then the exception won't be caught, though. Would you please explain this one further? Thank you.

Comment: The point of the `except: raise` is to *not* catch the exception (which is why it was fine to catch all exceptions in the first place: they would have just been re-raised).

Comment: Ah, I got it. Thanks. Appreciate the clarification.

Comment: @HCLivess: you're very welcome. Happy coding to you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can just put the common code after the try-catch block in `finally` block, something like this :

```
busy = 1
try:
    print 1/0
except:    
    raise
finally :
    busy = 0
    print busy
```

As you wanted to set `busy = 0` and `print busy` irrespective of `try-catch`, you can just put the common code outside the `try-catch` inside `finally` which will be executed eventually.

You can refer to [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) for more understanding.

Comment: That won’t `print busy` if an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Use `finally` clause or use a function in the `except` block.

```
busy = 1

def final(busy):
    print busy
    return busy

try:
    print 1/0
except:
    busy = final(0) #sets busy to 0
```